# ActiveAdmin performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

Imagine that you have **ActiveAdmin**, where index action presents data of model with many relations. There are few `:scope` with counter, some filters with ManyToMany related values, and in the table, one column from related (ManyToOne) model. Rendering it is true performance killer, aspecially when you combine filter with a scope or few filters.
I should not remove anything from the view. Currently there are 4 tables in `:scoped_collection` and in worse case scenario I have few selects with **6 JOINs** (scope counters, etc).
How could I optimize it? I was thinking about adding **ElasticSearch**, but I'm not sure if I am going the right direction...

Comment: It depends on the data. It's likely wrong direction. Recomputation of this data will be intense. If you cache it and compose a simpler cache invalidation mechanism (invalidating only changed data), then you'll greatly reduce load on requests in rapid succession. That said, a lot of changes at once will eliminate the effect, but only for one following request, when the data is regenerated. In fact, this will distribute the load from this specific request to many other requests in your app. A tradeoff, of course.